# Debugging a multithreaded program

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gdb

While debugging a multithreaded c program using GDB, how do I find out the execution position of individual threads in situations like " the execution of a program hanging midway".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit Contol-C to get the `(gdb)` prompt, and then `thread apply all where`.